# refreshLocal in Eclipse does not work properly

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have a program that changes an input Java project loaded in Eclipse. After changes I use the below code to refresh the project and extract compilation unit.

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

//projectName is the name of project loaded in eclipse  
IProject project = root.getProject(projectName);

try {
    project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
 } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

IJavaProject iJavaproject = JavaCore.create(project);

/** Extract ICompilationUnit. "classFullName" is the name of class contains new changes.*/
ICompilationUnit iCompilationUnit = getICompilationUnit(javaProject, classFullName);

/** Extract compilation unit.*/
CompilationUnit compilationUnit = getCompilationUnit(iCompilationUnit);
```

I have these two functions to extract iCompilationUnit and compilationUnit.

```
private ICompilationUnit getICompilationUnit(IJavaProject javaProject, String classFullName) {

    ICompilationUnit iUnit = null;
    try {
        IType iType = javaProject.findType(classFullName);
        iUnit = iType.getCompilationUnit();

        /** Create working copy. It is safer to work with a copy.*/
        WorkingCopyOwner owner = iUnit.getOwner();
        iUnit = (owner == null ? iUnit.getWorkingCopy(null) : iUnit.getWorkingCopy(owner, null)); 
    } catch (JavaModelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return iUnit;
}

CompilationUnit getCompilationUnit(ICompilationUnit iCompilationUnit) {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(iCompilationUnit);

    /** we need bindings later on.*/
    parser.setResolveBindings(true); 
    return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
}
```

However, the problem I am facing is that first call to this method (first time that any changes is applied to the project), the above code cannot detect changes and return original version. However, after that the project is refreshed correctly and final compilationUnit contains applied changes.

I am not sure the problem is for refreshLocal and maybe it is for other two functions: getCompilationUnit and getICompilationUnit.

Please let me know if any one has any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the JDT is probably running background jobs to recompile and rebuild indices. So you need to wait for those jobs to finish. Try

```
IJobManager jobManager = Job.getJobManager();

jobManager.join(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_MANUAL_BUILD, monitor);

jobManager.join(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_AUTO_BUILD, monitor);
```

do this after the `refreshLocal` but before you do anything else.

Comment: The pause would have to be **after** the refreshLocal, it is events generated during the refreshLocal which triggers JDT to start the builds. Similarly the `join` calls must be after the `refreshLocal`.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more I don't think a scheduling rule can be used to delay the job correctly so the `join` method has to be used.

Comment: I accept the answer. The problem happens as JDT is running background jobs. Adding this instruction after refreshLocal solved the problem. **jobManager.join(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_AUTO_BUILD, null);**

Comment: I also found adding **jobManager.wakeUp(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_AUTO_BUILD);** before join can increase the speed (at least in my program).